# Posicionar elemento Div con otro Div en linea CSS

Tags: html, css

Quiero posicionar 2 elementos de tal forma que queden en linea,
la estrutura es asi; Un elemento Div tiene dentro 2 divs; quiero poner el boton que tiene el logo de camara a la derecha, a un lado del texto, donde esta marcado con la palomita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi base:
El color solido de la caja es solo para si esta posicionado..

```html
 

<div style="border:solid;">

<div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; border:solid;">
 <span>
  <strong>Nombre evento</strong>
   Descripcion evento
  </span>
</div>
<div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; border:solid;">
 <span >
  <button style="border-radius:5px;"  ><i ></i>Boton</button>
 </span>
</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: al `div` padre que contiene esos dos divs que queres dividir añádele estos estilos `display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;`

Comment: Hazlo como respuesta @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel  se alineo justo como quería, muchas gracias, puedes ponerlo como respuesta :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría `Flexbox` para poder hacerlo mas rápido te muestro el código que implemente y te explico dentro de el para que sirven, por otro lado si te interesa aprender mas sobre `Flexbox` te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.contenedor-flexbox {
    display: flex; /*Convertimos al menú en flexbox*/
    justify-content: space-between; /*Con esto le indicamos que margine todos los items que se encuentra adentro hacia la derecha e izquierda*/
    align-items: center; /*con esto alineamos de manera vertical*/
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-flexbox">
        <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; border:solid;">
         <span>
          <strong>Nombre evento</strong>
           Descripcion evento
          </span>
        </div>
        <div style="width:50%; display:inline-block; border:solid;">
         <span >
          <button style="border-radius:5px;"  ><i ></i>Boton</button>
         </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

pd: vi que estas usando los estilos de `css` dentro del `html`, te recomiendo que crees un archivo de `css` y que tengas ahí tus estilos separados y ordenados.

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto los estilos css los tengo por separado jeje y los llamo con clases, justo los adjunte a las clases :)